Proving $2^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$ divides the permanent of any $n\times n$ $(1,-1)$ matrix by induction and Laplace expansion
Page 2 of this paper
Wang, E.TH. On permanents of $(1, − 1)$-matrices. Israel J. Math. 18, 353–361 (1974).
https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02760844
contains the following proposition:
Let $\Omega_n$ denote the set of all $n\times n$ matrices in which each entry is $1$ or $-1$.
Let $A\in \Omega_n$. Then $\operatorname*{per}(A)\equiv 0 \pmod{2^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}}$
The proposition is proved by first proving the case $n=2$, then proceed by induction on $n$ and Laplace expansion. However, the details of the inductive step was omitted and I have trouble filling in the details.
Here is my attempt:
Suppose the claim is true for some $n\ge2$. Let $A\in \Omega_{n+1}$. By Laplace expansion, we have $\operatorname*{per}(A) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n+1} a_{1i} \operatorname*{per}(A_{1i})$, where $A_{1j}$ represents the $n\times n$ $(i,j)$-minor. By induction hypothesis, we have $\operatorname*{per}(A_{1i})=2^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}k_{1i}$ for some integer $k_{1i}$. We have
$$\operatorname*{per}(A) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n+1} 2^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}a_{1i} k_{1i}=2^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}\sum_{i = 1}^{n+1}a_{1i} k_{1i}$$
If $n$ is even, then we have $2^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}=2^{\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \rfloor}$ so $2^{\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \rfloor}$ $\mid$ $\operatorname*{per}(A)$.
I don't know how to show that if $n$ is odd, then we would have $2 \mid \sum_{i = 1}^{n+1}a_{1i} k_{1i}$, which would give us one more factor of $2$ that is required to prove $2^{\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \rfloor}$ $\mid$ $\operatorname*{per}(A)$.

I think the right approach is inducting from $n-2$ to $n$, using Laplace expansion with respect to the last two rows (or columns, if you wish).

This solution was inspired by @darij grinberg comment.
The claim is clearly true for $n=1$ and $n=2$.
Let $A\in \Omega_n$.
By Laplace expansion, we have
$$\operatorname*{per}(A) = \sum_{j = 1}^{n} a_{n,j} \operatorname*{per}(A_{n,j})$$
Then, by using laplace expansion on each $\operatorname*{per}(A_{n,j})$ with respect to the last row and rearranging the terms, we obtain
$$\operatorname*{per}(A) = \sum_{1\le i\lt j\le n}^{n}(a_{n,j}a_{n-1,i}+a_{n-1,j}a_{n,i})\operatorname*{per}(A_{n-1,n,i,j})$$
where each $A_{n-1,n,i,j}$ is the $(n-2)\times(n-2)$ submatrix formed by removing the $(n-1)^{th},n^{th}$ rows and the $i^{th},j^{th}$ columns.
By induction hypotheses, we have $$\operatorname*{per}(A) = \sum_{1\le i\lt j\le n}^{n}(a_{n,j}a_{n-1,i}+a_{n-1,j}a_{n,i})2^{\lfloor\frac{n-2}{2}\rfloor}k_{i,j}$$where $k_{i,j}$ are integers.
Since each entry of $A$ is either $1$ or $-1$, we have $2\mid a_{n,j}a_{n-1,i}+a_{n-1,j}a_{n,i}$.
Therefore, $2^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\mid \operatorname*{per}(A)$.
